# Why a knapsack problem is not solvable in a polynomial time with an algorithm using dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, knapsack-problem

I saw this explanation but I still could not fully understand it.
If we follow this logic: Suppose some algorithm works in O(n) time, then:
Let's assume n = 1000 in binary term (4-bit long)
so the time complexity `T(n) = O(8)`
Let’s double the size of input. `n = 10000000 (8-bit long) T(n) = O(128)`
The time increases in exponential term, so it means that `O(n)` is not a polynomial time?

[image: explanation]

Comment: Which bits do you not understand? Given that you have already posted what amounts to an answer, its a bit difficult to see how to help.

Comment: By this logic it follows that o(n) is not a polynomial time, though it actually is.

Comment: If I understand the logic correctly, I think this is a Proof by Contradiction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction

Comment: The way the big-O notation is used in that screenshot makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

The question is: "Polynomial as a function of *what*?". When we determine complexity of algorithms, we usually, but not always, express it as a function of **the length of the input**. Often, but not always, this length is represented by the letter `n`. For instance, if you study problems involving graphs, the letter `n` is often used to denote the number of vertices in the graph, rather than for the length of the input.

In your case, the variable `n` is the number of items, and variable `W` is the capacity of the bag.

Thus, the number `n` is relevant to the complexity; but it is not, in itself, the entire length of the input. Let's call `N` the real length of the input. Try not to confuse `n` and `N`. The complexity of your algorithms will have to be expressed as functions of `N`, and terms like "linear complexity", "polynomial complexity", "exponential complexity", etc., will always be in reference to `N`, not `n`.

What is the length `N` of the input?

Your input consists in a list of pairs `(weight(i), value(i))`, followed by the capacity `W`. Presumably, each item in the bag is allowed to have a weight ranging from `0` to `W`; and a value ranging from `0` to some max value `V`. Thus, weights need as many bits as `W` to be expressed, and values need as many bits as `V` to be expressed.

If you know a little about logarithms and about writing numbers, you should know that the number of bits required to write a number is proportional to its logarithm. Thus, every weight requires `log(W)` bits, and every value requires `log(V)` bits.

Thus: `N = n * (log(W) + log(V))`.

You can convince yourself that the lengths of `W` and `V` are relevant to the complexity. Here all our numbers are integers. But imagine a real world problem. A weight can be expressed in tons, or in grams. `1 ton` is the same as `1000000 grams`. A value can be expressed in cents, or in tens of thousands of euros. Before inputting our real-world problem into our algorithm, we need to choose our units.

Is your algorithm going to take a longer time to solve the problem, if the weight is expressed in grams rather than in tons?

The answer is yes. Because grams are a million times more precise than tons. So you are asking for a million times more precise answer, when asking the question in grams rather than in tons. Thus the algorithm will take more time to find that solution.

I hope I could convince you that the complexity of the algorithm should be expressed as a function of the actual length of the input, and not just the number of elements.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really very helpful. But what about values? Besides, to represent the vector of items [1, 2, 3, ... n ] does not the computer must convert them into binary? (1->1,  2->10 , 3-> 11,  4->100 ...). What about them?

Comment: @Fibonacci The length of a number `n` written in decimal is `log10(n)`. The length of a the same number `n` written in binary is `log2(n)`. You are technically correct that the length of these two writings is technically not exactly the same. However, as it so happens, logarithms in different bases are proportional: for any number `n`, the ratio `log2(n) / log10(n)` will always be equal to `log2(10)`, which is about `3.32`. So "the length of `n`" remains the same up to a constant factor, notwithstanding the chosen base.

Comment: @Fibonacci Note that this is also why you might have often seen people use the notation `O(log(n))`, but never `O(log2(n))` or `O(log10(n))`. Normally, the notation `log(n)` is ambiguous, since it is unclear which logarithm it refers to. But when encapsulated in `O( )`, specifying the base becomes irrelevant.